# Am I doing something wrong with the PHP SOAP_CLIENT?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a very basic knowledge about SOAP, for me I think of SOAP as a translator for two different people, which both speaks different languages, trying to communicate with each other. I am trying to invoke a method from a web service using PHP SOAP CLIENT but I can't get it working, below is the WSDL generated by the web service server:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://server.webservice.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="serviceServerService" targetNamespace="http://server.webservice.com/">
<wsdl:types>
<schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://server.webservice.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<import namespace="http://server.webservice.com/" schemaLocation="http://127.0.0.1:8080/WebbServiceServer/services/serviceServerPort?xsd=serviceserver_schema1.xsd"/>
</schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="userInputResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:userInputResponse" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="userInput">
<wsdl:part element="tns:userInput" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="serviceInterface">
<wsdl:operation name="userInput">
<wsdl:input message="tns:userInput" name="userInput"></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:userInputResponse" name="userInputResponse"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="serviceServerServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:serviceInterface">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="userInput">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="userInput">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="userInputResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="serviceServerService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:serviceServerServiceSoapBinding" name="serviceServerPort">
<soap:address location="http://127.0.0.1:8080/WebbServiceServer/services/serviceServerPort"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

What I understand from the WSDL above is that the method that I'm trying to call is the `userInput` which takes a string argument and the `userInputResponse` is the response from the server which will output whatever the `userInput` method returned. Below is the code for PHP CLIENT that I am trying to run:

```
<?php
$a = array("userInput" => "This is the input");
$client = new SoapClient("http://127.0.0.1:8080/WebbServiceServer/services/serviceServerPort?wsdl", array('exceptions' => 0));

$result = $client->userInput($a);
//$functions = $client->__getFunctions();
//var_dump($client->__soapCall("userInput", $a));
//var_dump($functions);

print_r($result->userInputResponse);

if (is_soap_fault($result)) {
    trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$result->faultcode}, faultstring: {$result->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
}
?>
```

I tried running the PHP CLIENT unfortunately it print the error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$userInputResponse in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_SOAP_CLIENT\index.php on line 14
```

To test if the client did invoked the method `userInput` I use the `var_dump()` if something was returned:

```
var_dump($result);
```

and the output was:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["return"]=> string(56) "Hi! this is from JAVA Web services, your input was: null" }
```

fine it did return something but the method did not get the string that I passed. I am hoping that someone could identify and explain the flaws of my code, any comments and answers are greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use the property userInputResponse when it is not defined. When using classes, it is like a DOM tree of variables and such. So it looks like this maybe `root->subclass->prop`. Maybe this clears something up.

Comment: LOL, I got it now I did not look at the schema which contain the right name of the parameters I was invoking the root, `<xs:complexType name="userInput">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" **name="arg0"** type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="userInputResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" **name="return"** type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>`

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt of accessing the return value is wrong. There is no property `userInputResponse`, as you can see in your `var_dump()`. In fact, the return value is store in a property `return`.

I cannot really see that this is defined in the WSDL, but I think it is incomplete. There is a reference to another XSD which might be loaded as well and can contain further definitions.

Comment: Thanks man that is exactly the mistake, I didn't check the other XSD located `http://127.0.0.1:8080/WebbServiceServer/services/serviceServerPort?xsd=serviceserver_schema1.xsd` which contains other definitions.